# Manage puppet master using puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Has anyone experience with creating and managing puppet masters through puppet itself?

We are running a control-repo and currently some of the puppet masters files (mainly for plugins) are managed through a puppet role. I would like to take this one step further and allow automatic creation of a new puppet master and manage the complete puppet master configuration through puppet, including installation. This would make it easy to create masters for testing and upgrade purposes. We have all the code to bootstrap a new server with a particular role.

I'm trying to automate this: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/installing/installing_pe.html#install-using-text-mode-split-configuration

But having difficulty making things occur in the correct sequence, because I don't know how to get a puppet agent to repeat the puppet agent run immediately, from within puppet. I suppose mcollective might help, by sending the commands to the local and remote hosts, but again would that work from within puppet?. Does anyone have experience with this? Or should I just give up and add the initial installation of the master and the coordination of other actions to our bootstrap code? Perhaps using mcollective?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  For Puppet to manage anything on a given machine, it needs to already be installed on that machine.  Are you trying to make it install a separate Puppet instance, then?

Comment: Using an existing master to prepare a new master, which would be used for testing or preparing upgrades. A bit like compiling the new version of a compiler with the existing version. The agent is already installed with our bootstrap image.

Comment: I would recommend using Packer with Puppet for this. It would achieve what you want and be easy and reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use AWS CF to do this. You can create and ec2 instance quickly with CloudFormation and bootstrape the node with puppet server and agent installed. You can also terminate and repeat the process as many times you want.

See process here https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithPuppet.pdf

Comment: We're in a private cloud. But the principle is exactly what I want to achieve. A good starting point thanks.